# NHibernate InvalidCastException in AsBooleanExpression, class HqlTreeNodeExtensions in HQLTreeNode.cs

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, nhibernate, .net

:
     I have a problem... I opted to use NHibernate 3.3.3 sources instead of the pre-compiled DLL because I'm getting sick of having NHibernate issues and not be able to debug them (ie black box). I did the same with fluent NHibernate.

I tested the source I compiled for fluent NHibernate with the precompiled NHibernate DLL and it worked. So I decided to go further and do the same with NHibernate.
     This is where it sucks : my app starts, search engine vorks, etc... BUT every time I try to save something, I get an InvalidCastException in the "AsBooleanExpression" method of class HqlTreeNodeExtensions (in file HQLTreeNode.cs) when it recieves a value of type "NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HQLBitWiseAnd", not being able to cast it as NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression.

Why it worked on the compiled DLL and doesn't works in source? I know 0 about the internals of NHibernate, and just a little about c# as I am a VB developper..

This is where it happens :

```
public static class HqlTreeNodeExtensions
{
    public static HqlExpression AsExpression(this HqlTreeNode node)
    {
        // TODO - nice error handling if cast fails
        return (HqlExpression)node;
    }

    public static HqlBooleanExpression AsBooleanExpression(this HqlTreeNode node)
    {
        if (node is HqlDot)
        {
            return new HqlBooleanDot(node.Factory, (HqlDot) node);
        }


        // TODO - nice error handling if cast fails
        return (HqlBooleanExpression)node;  <-------- RIGHT HERE - the cast fails      
    }
}
```

(Can't post image for stack calls; will try to convert it as readavle text)

Can someone help he?

Many Thanks

Nico

P.S. Here is the full call stack :
Ok; here we go for the full call stack : 
Excerpt from my own code : All begins at the line "Dim ctrlResultatsRecherche As New ResultatsRechercheClientV2..."

```
    Private Sub RechercheClient_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtCodePostal.KeyDown, txtClient.KeyDown, txtRue.KeyDown, txtVille.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

            Dim bolMaibecExpress As Boolean = False

            'Récupérer le contrôle parent.
            If Not Parent Is Nothing AndAlso TypeOf Parent.Parent Is SaisieDemandeEchantillon Then
                bolMaibecExpress = TryCast(Parent.Parent, SaisieDemandeEchantillon).chkMaibecExpress.Checked
            End If

            panDetails.Controls.DisposeAndRemoveAll()
            Dim ctrlResultatsRecherche As New ResultatsRechercheClientV2(m_Session, txtClient.Text, txtCodePostal.Text, txtVille.Text, txtRue.Text, bolMaibecExpress) 
            AddHandler ctrlResultatsRecherche.ClientSelectionneV2, AddressOf RésultatsRecherche_ClientSélectionné
            panDetails.Controls.Add(ctrlResultatsRecherche)
            panDetails.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

then Excerpt from my own code : stops at the line "Dim resultats = m_Session.Query(Of Client).Where(predicat.Expand).ToList"

```
Public Sub New(ByVal session As ISession, ByVal strClient As String, ByVal strCodePostal As String, ByVal strVille As String, ByVal strRue As String, Optional ByVal MaibecExpress As Boolean = False)

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    dgvResultatsRecherche.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    m_Session = session

    Dim predicat = PredicateBuilder.False(Of Client)()
    predicat = predicat.Or(Function(x As Client) (x.Prenom.Contains(strClient) OrElse x.Nom.Contains(strClient) OrElse x.Telephone.Contains(strClient) OrElse x.Courriel.Contains(strClient) OrElse strClient = "") _
                                                And (x.Adresse.CodePostal.Contains(strCodePostal) Or strCodePostal = "") _
                                                And (x.Adresse.Ville.Contains(strVille) Or strVille = "") _
                                                And (x.Adresse.Ligne1.Contains(strRue) Or strRue = "") _
                                                And (x.MaibecExpress = MaibecExpress Or MaibecExpress = False))

    Dim resultats = m_Session.Query(Of Client).Where(predicat.Expand).ToList
    dgvResultatsRecherche.DataSource = resultats
    lblNbResultatsTrouvés.Text = String.Format("{0} résultats trouvés", resultats.Count)
    SetDataBindings()
End Sub
```

then a call to remotion.link.dll -> Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase.GetEnumerator() (sorry, don't have the code)

Then execute sub from NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider, at the "NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression = PrepareQuery(expression, out query, out nhQuery);" line

```
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return (TResult) Execute(expression);
    }
```

Then execute sub from NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider, at the "return" line

```
    public virtual object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        IQuery query;
        NhLinqExpression nhQuery;
        NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression = PrepareQuery(expression, out query, out nhQuery);

        return ExecuteQuery(nhLinqExpression, query, nhQuery);
    }
```

Then PrepareQuery from NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider, at the "query = Session.CreateQuery(nhLinqExpression);" line

```
    protected NhLinqExpression PrepareQuery(Expression expression, out IQuery query, out NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
    {
        var nhLinqExpression = new NhLinqExpression(expression, Session.Factory);

        query = Session.CreateQuery(nhLinqExpression);

        nhQuery = query.As<ExpressionQueryImpl>().QueryExpression.As<NhLinqExpression>();

        SetParameters(query, nhLinqExpression.ParameterValuesByName);
        SetResultTransformerAndAdditionalCriteria(query, nhQuery, nhLinqExpression.ParameterValuesByName);
        return nhLinqExpression;
    }
```

Then CreateQuery sub from NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl, at the "var queryPlan = GetHQLQueryPlan(queryExpression, false);" line

```
    public virtual IQuery CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
    {
        using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
        {
            CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus();
            var queryPlan = GetHQLQueryPlan(queryExpression, false);
            var query = new ExpressionQueryImpl(queryPlan.QueryExpression, 
                                            this,
                                            queryPlan.ParameterMetadata
                                            );
            query.SetComment("[expression]");
            return query;
        }
    }
```

then GetHQLQueryPlan sub from NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl (jams at the return line)

```
    protected internal virtual IQueryExpressionPlan GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, bool shallow)
    {
        using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
        {
            return factory.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(queryExpression, shallow, EnabledFilters);
        }
    }
```

then GetHQLQueryPlan sub from NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlan(jams at line Plan = new HQLExpressionQueryPlan (...))

```
    public IQueryExpressionPlan GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, bool shallow, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
    {
        string expressionStr = queryExpression.Key;

        var key = new HQLQueryPlanKey(queryExpression, shallow, enabledFilters);
        var plan = (IQueryExpressionPlan)planCache[key];

        if (plan == null)
        {
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.Debug("unable to locate HQL query plan in cache; generating (" + expressionStr + ")");
            }
            plan = new HQLExpressionQueryPlan(expressionStr, queryExpression, shallow, enabledFilters, factory);
            planCache.Put(key, plan);
        }
        else
        {
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.Debug("located HQL query plan in cache (" + expressionStr + ")");
            }
            var planExpression = plan.QueryExpression as NhLinqExpression;
            var expression = queryExpression as NhLinqExpression;
            if (planExpression != null && expression != null)
            {
                //NH-3413
                //Here we have to use original expression.
                //In most cases NH do not translate expression in second time, but 
                // for cases when we have list parameters in query, like @p1.Contains(...),
                // it does, and then it uses parameters from first try. 
                //TODO: cache only required parts of QueryExpression
                planExpression._expression = expression._expression;
                planExpression._constantToParameterMap = expression._constantToParameterMap;
            }
        }

        return plan;
    }
```

then in HQLExpressionQueryPlan (skipped the properties), at the return line :

```
    private static IQueryTranslator[] CreateTranslators(string expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, string collectionRole, bool shallow, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    {
        IQueryTranslatorFactory2 qtFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();

        return qtFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(expressionStr, queryExpression, collectionRole, shallow, enabledFilters, factory);
    }
```

then in ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.cs, at the return line :

```
    public IQueryTranslator[] CreateQueryTranslators(string queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, string collectionRole, bool shallow, IDictionary<string, IFilter> filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    {
        return CreateQueryTranslators(queryExpression.Translate(factory), queryIdentifier, collectionRole, shallow,
                                      filters, factory);
    }
```

In QueryModelVisitor.cs, in GenerateHqlQuery (Excerpt only) at the Visitor.Visit() line 
            //...
            // Identify and name query sources
            QuerySourceIdentifier.Visit(parameters.QuerySourceNamer, queryModel);

```
        var visitor = new QueryModelVisitor(parameters, root, queryModel) { RewrittenOperatorResult = result };
        visitor.Visit();

        return visitor._hqlTree.GetTranslation();
```

Then a couple of calls to Remotion DLL for which I don't have the code...
And then, in QueryModelVisitor.cs, in VisitWhereClause, at line var expression =...

```
    public override void VisitWhereClause(WhereClause whereClause, QueryModel queryModel, int index)
    {
        // Visit the predicate to build the query
        var expression = HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.Visit(whereClause.Predicate, VisitorParameters).AsBooleanExpression();
        if (whereClause is NhHavingClause)
        {
            _hqlTree.AddHavingClause(expression);
        }
        else
        {
            _hqlTree.AddWhereClause(expression);
        }
    }
```

then in HQLGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.cs, in visit function, line return :

```
    public static HqlTreeNode Visit(Expression expression, VisitorParameters parameters)
    {
        return new HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor(parameters).VisitExpression(expression);
    }
```

Then, in the same file, line return VisitBinaryExpression((BinaryExpression) expression) - (Excerpt only):

```
            //...
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
            case ExpressionType.LessThan:
            case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
            case ExpressionType.Coalesce:
            case ExpressionType.ArrayIndex:
                return VisitBinaryExpression((BinaryExpression) expression);
            case ExpressionType.Conditional:
                return VisitConditionalExpression((ConditionalExpression) expression);
            case ExpressionType.Constant:
                return VisitConstantExpression((ConstantExpression) expression);
            //...
```

Same file, function VisitBinaryExpression,  linereturn _hqlTreeBuilder.BooleanOr(lhs.AsBooleanExpression(), rhs.AsBooleanExpression()) - Excerpt only

```
            //...
            case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
                return _hqlTreeBuilder.BooleanAnd(lhs.AsBooleanExpression(), rhs.AsBooleanExpression());

            case ExpressionType.Or:
                return _hqlTreeBuilder.BitwiseOr(lhs, rhs);

            case ExpressionType.OrElse:
                return _hqlTreeBuilder.BooleanOr(lhs.AsBooleanExpression(), rhs.AsBooleanExpression());

            case ExpressionType.Add:
                if (expression.Left.Type == typeof (string) && expression.Right.Type == typeof (string))
                {
                    return _hqlTreeBuilder.MethodCall("concat", lhs, rhs);
                }
                return _hqlTreeBuilder.Add(lhs, rhs);       
            //...
```

And finally, in HQLTreeNode.cs, line return (HqlBooleanExpression)node , near the weird todo comment :

```
public static class HqlTreeNodeExtensions
{
    public static HqlExpression AsExpression(this HqlTreeNode node)
    {
        // TODO - nice error handling if cast fails
        return (HqlExpression)node;
    }

    public static HqlBooleanExpression AsBooleanExpression(this HqlTreeNode node)
    {
        if (node is HqlDot)
        {
            return new HqlBooleanDot(node.Factory, (HqlDot) node);
        }

        // TODO - nice error handling if cast fails
        return (HqlBooleanExpression)node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably breaking on the thrown exception but if you continue (F5) the exception will be handled at a higher level in the NHibernate source. Although the comments in the source code make me suspicious. Try this: in Visual Studio go to Debug > Exceptions and uncheck the checkbox in the Thrown column for Common Language Runtime Exceptions.